# change select value in HTML5 template

Tags: html

I can change the value of a HTML select using JavaScript, but it fails when the select is in a HTML5 template.

For example, here is the HTML code:

```
<template id="sel_template">
<select id="sel">
    <option value="1">Cat</option>
    <option value="2">Dog</option>
    <option value="3">Fish</option>
</select>
</template>

<div id="put_here">
</div>
```

And the JavaScript code:

```
var t = document.querySelector("#sel_template");
var val = 2;    
t.content.querySelector('#sel [value="' + val + '"]').selected = true;
var clone = document.importNode(t.content,true);
document.querySelector("#put_here").appendChild(clone);
```

The select value is "Cat" instead of "Fish".

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dfroger/29kmerjh/1/

What's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `setAttribute`:

```
t.content.querySelector('#sel [value="' + val + '"]').setAttribute('selected', 'selected');
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/29kmerjh/3/)